# How infrequent is “a non-zero chance”?

Tags: numbers, colloquialisms, north-american-english

I misinterpreted the expression “a non-zero chance” as an emphatic way to stress that there was no possibility or likelihood of something happening.

- *there is **a non-zero chance** that they will pay attention to some of the responses…*
- *there is **a non-zero chance** that the feedback may matter.*

The author explained

> **NB**: …the chance of them changing it is *not zero* and therefore must be more than that. I used a double-negative to emphasize that, while there is a chance, it probably isn't a *good* chance.
>
> **Me**: It's confusing and ambiguous... why not just say "slim chance"?
>
> **NB**: Because I prefer 'non-zero chance'; I like the phrasing of it. I like using double-negation as a way to minimize something. And for the record, thus far you appear to be the only person who has mentioned being confused by this phrase.

- Does “a non-zero chance” mean ‘more than zero’?
- Is the author right? Am I the only person who could misinterpret this phrasing?
- Is this phrasing peculiar to American speakers or do British speakers use this expression too?

P.S  someone posted this link to an SE Mathematics question: [Zero probability and impossibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility/41114#41114) but I didn't understand *a thing*

Comment: ***non-zero*** - 


Having a positive or negative value; not equal to zero.
*‘an extremely small but non-zero chance’*  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-zero

Comment: I’ve always intuitively understood it to mean “a greater than zero chance”, and have only ever heard it used in those contexts. I think it would be hard for me to interpret it any other way, as probabilities can’t be negative, they can only be positive or nil, and the expression says it’s not nil. (But of course because we’re choosing to contrast it specifically with zero, instead of saying “a good chance” or “a decent chance”, then the implication is the chances are not zero, but not high either: slim).

Comment: Here’s a tangentially related anecdote which is probably only funny if you’re a trader or live among them (but I’m gonna tell it anyway): I was in a meeting with an equities trader, and we were talking about some poor stock that was taking a beating. He said one of his colleagues was saying the bottom was dropping out and the security had no support. He tells me he responded “No no, it has *plenty* of support... **down around zero**”. He laughed at his own wit for like 3 minutes. For context, *support* is jargon in technical analysis meaning people would buy at that level, resisting more drop.

Comment: Also, whoever you were talking to was misguided in his interpretation of the grammar. This is definitely *not* double negation. The *zero* isn’t negating, it’s quantifying, and the *not* is negating that specific quantification. It’s like saying “This house costs a million dollars. // Well, I don’t have a million bucks. // Ok, so how many bucks have you got? // Not a million, anyway” (only here, by contrast, the negation of a *high* number [in context] is implying it’s a *low* number).

Comment: @DanBron why don't you post an answer?? C'mon slow day here at home, the rest of the week I'm too busy to spend quality time on Q&As

Comment: @Mari-LouA Alright, I know the slow day blues. I’ll post it in a little bit. But I’m keeping the trading joke in!

Comment: Probability can never be negative. So a 'non-zero' probability simply expresses that there is a _positive outcome_. The author is mistaken that it conveys the idea of a 'small chance'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, this way of speaking is not peculiar to Americans (or people from any other region), but it is peculiar to people whose education or profession makes them used to thinking of probability in quantitative terms. Such people may say that something has the probability of zero, when others would say that it is impossible. Once you get used to thinking and speaking in this way, it is natural to say 'non-zero chance' for something that is possible.

Comment: There's a huge difference between regular language and technical (statistical or mathematical) language. The difference is crucial in this question.

Comment: @lambie this term may qualify as technical jargon but I don’t think it’s interpretable any other way—either it is meaningless or means that ther is some level of possibility

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I agree with you that it is poor phrasing, but I take it in the opposite way (barring further context, anyway): rather than conveying that it is "nearly impossible", NB's use of "non-zero" clearly emphasizes that something is, in fact, possible.   If they wanted to say "it's not bloody likely" then they should have phrased it some other way.

Comment: @Hellion oh, thank you! The "it's not bloody likely" is exactly how I interpreted NB's message, so I understood the context and the sense of "a non-zero"  but not its literal meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The miscommunication between the OP and her interlocutor is an example of what sometimes happens in interaction between people whose ways of speaking are shaped by an education or professional experience that revolves around analysing phenomena in quantitative terms, and those with other kinds of backgrounds. The differences that the latter group characterises as qualitative, may be quite spontaneously characterised as quantitative by the former. (So, no, the OP is far from being the only person to have had the experience of such miscommunication.)

Consider, for example, the difference between moving and standing still. To many people that is probably a very clear, definite, qualitative difference. Such people may speak of moving things as having this or that speed, but would never speak of the speed of an object that is standing still. A scientifically trained person, on the other hand, finds it quite natural to say that such an object has the speed that equals zero. In such a person’s conceptual framework, the difference between moving and standing still is merely quantitative; it’s the difference between having the speed of zero and having some other speed. A person who is accustomed to this way of thinking may feel compelled, when speaking of things that are in fact moving, to say that they have some non-zero speed; to people on the other side, ‘non-zero’ in such a context seems redundant, as they would never apply the concept of speed to motionless things.

Now, the same division can be seen when people speak of probabilities. The everyday framework for conceptualising them has the concepts such as impossible, possible (but improbable), probable (likely), certain. The differences among these at first appear to be qualitative, and are spoken of as such. People who are trained to analyse probabilities in quantitative terms, however, think of them as a continuum between zero and one. In that framework, something that is impossible has the probability of zero, something that is certain has the probability of one, and everything that is possible but not certain has some probability that is between these extremes. A person who is accustomed to that framework may feel the need to use the phrase ‘non-zero probability’ or ‘non-zero chance’ to make it clear that whatever is talked about is not impossible. To a person who is not accustomed to it, such a phrase seems strange, just like the non-zero speed in the above example. (Incidentally, to answer directly the question posed in the title, yes, non-zero in this context means more than zero as the scale of probabilities does not go below zero.)

So, saying that something has a non-zero chance is just a way of saying that it is possible, that comes naturally to people who have a certain educational or professional background, but may be confusing to those who don’t. Contrary to what the OP suspected, this way of speaking is not peculiar to Americans or to speakers of any other regional variation of the language. In fact, the whole matter is not specific to English, as analogous differences between people of different educational/professional backgrounds can probably be found among speakers of any language.

Now, the miscommunication between the OP and her interlocutor had another layer that was superimposed on this. The term *non-zero chance*, just like the more mundane term *possible*, by its meaning covers a wide range, from the probabilities that are just a sliver above zero, all the way to one. However, it would be strange and misleading (but not false) to use either of these terms if one knew that the probability is very high. Although these terms do not logically entail that the probability is low, they do imply it (in the loose, everyday sense of *imply*), or implicate it, or suggest it. In other words they convey the idea that the probability is low, as a matter of pragmatics, but not as a matter of semantics.

Answer (score 4):

The author is "right" in the sense that in his/her books, *zero chance* is already a negative. There may be some merit in this, as witnessed by this dictionary entry for **zero**:

> He said that his chances of getting the job were zero (= he had no chance).

[-- source --](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zero)

The word *zero* in this entry is an adjective. The meaning of *non-zero* should be intuitive then; or, as Lewis Carroll would have it, if one understands the term "zero chance", then one is bound to understand "non-zero chance", too.

There is some merit in using *non-zero chance* as opposed to *slim chance* or any other more precise qualification, especially if you really do not know what the chance might be. *Non-zero chance* commits to very little: merely, that you believe the event is **possible**.

The quoted entry might also be taken for supportive evidence for there being no essential difference in BrE and AmE usage.

Answer (score 1):

> Does “a non-zero chance” mean ‘more than zero’?

YES

**non zero**  [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-zero)

> ‘an extremely **small** but **non-zero chance**’

Your question:

> Is this phrasing peculiar to American speakers or do British speakers
>   use this expression too?

I hear and use this In AmE frequently.  My sense is to imply a minuscule chance, a slim chance, a small chance etc...

Here are some usages recently in AmE news/magazines:

> “Here’s a pretty incredible fact: There is **a non-zero chance** that
>   Donald Trump isn’t paying *any* taxes,” Clinton tweeted, just minutes
>   after releasing her own returns. Time Aug 11, 2016

and

> If he starts treating your mother in a way that suggests a potential
>   for abuse, you should absolutely intervene, but there’s a **non-zero
>   chance** that he’s just happily dating an older woman. Slate Jun 27,
>   2016

and

> So it’s important to check as soon as possible with your local Social
>   Security office to see if you do quality for a non-zero excess spousal
>   benefit. Forbes Jan 2015

And here are BrE usages in the same sense I am supporting:

> **[Economics, Uncertainty and European Football: Trends in Competitive Balance](https://books.google.com/books?id=fHQnlF2LJawC&lpg=PA26&dq=%22non%20zero%20chance%22%20in%20european%20literature&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=%22non%20zero%20chance%22%20in%20european%20literature&f=false)** "For CB, each competitor in a match must really have a
>   significant (i.e. **non-zero) chance** of winning."

and

> A 2014 study of chess experts, including Carlsen, shows that they
>   consistently attribute a modest – but **non-zero** – contribution of
>   **chance** factors to game outcomes.  [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2016/sep/22/chance-is-ever-present-in-the-game-of-chess) Sept 2016

In summary, it is used by both AmE and BrE speakers in the same sense, probably more predominately in the U.S.

Comment: What are the different senses in AmEng and BrEng?

Comment: @Mari-LouA There aren’t any, so far as I know. I believe lbf put that in as a hedge to say “my comments may only apply to my own dialect, I am not sure they can be generalized”. But the fact that it inspires questions like yours is why I wish answers wouldn’t contain statements or assertions without corroborating evidence. If you don’t know something, leave it out.

Comment: attempted to address both comments.

Comment: There is nothing in “non zero chance” that indicates a slim chance. It is maybe more likely that you would refer to something as non zero when it’s close to zero but 80% is also non-zero

Comment: Note that nonzero doesn't necessarily mean strictly positive. When speaking about probability, sure, but it's used in other situations as well (e.g. a nonzero value).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean a slim chance, but it does imply either a low chance or a completely unknown chance. The basic rules of conversation suggest that if you knew it was a good/high chance you would say so, while "non-zero" is used where you are unable to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The author is *technically* correct -- others have already pointed out that 'non-zero' is not a double-negative.

In a purely technical (and somewhat pedantic) sense, a 'non-zero' chance is distinct from a 'slim chance'.  A 'slim chance' means that there's still a probability of something occurring at *some* point.  For example, there's a slim chance that the Mars rover will find evidence of life on the Red Planet tomorrow -- it's not particularly likely to happen, but there's a mathematically-reasonable probability.

A 'non-zero' chance, on the other hand, is often used to describe something that has such a vanishingly small probability of occurring that it might as well be 'zero chance'.  The oft-quoted '1,000 monkeys banging on 1,000 typewriters spontaneously typing out the complete works of William Shakespeare' is one example -- it's not *impossible*, but it's mathematically guaranteed that it will (probably) never actually happen.

Answer (score -1):

Probability can never be negative :

> The probability of the outcome of an experiment is **never negative**, but quasiprobability distributions can be defined that allow a negative probability, or quasiprobability for some events. These distributions may apply to **unobservable events** or conditional probabilities.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability)

So a 'non-zero' probability simply expresses that there is **a positive probability**.

The author is mistaken that it conveys the idea of a 'small chance'.

Comment: It is true that *non-zero* does not logically entail that the probability is small; it could be anything up to 100%. However, in virtue of standard conversational conventions it does imply (in the loose, everyday sense of *imply*), or implicate, or suggest, that it is small. In other words, it does not convey the idea of smallness as matter of semantics, but it does convey it as a matter of pragmatics.

Comment: How exactly do the reference to quasiprobabilities help the OP?

Comment: a 'small chance' is what is implied to this AmE reader.

Comment: If it doesn't imply a "small chance" does it mean any number is plausible? If I say that there is a non-zero chance of something happening, am I saying its *probability* is equal or greater to one?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, probability of something cannot be greater than one (or 100%). Probabilities, if one thinks of them quantitatively, range from zero (i.e. impossibility) to one (i.e. certainty). Note that an event that has the probability of, say, 3%, is not at all probable.

Comment: @jsw29 OK time for me to ask a stupid question, so when experts say that something has a one in a billion chance of happening, or that two out of five marriages are likely to end in divorce, is that the same probability?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, if two out of five marriages end in divorce, then the probability of a given marriage ending in divorce is 0.4 (or 40%), assuming we don't now anything specific about it. If something has one in a billion chance of happening, then its probability is 0.000000001.

Comment: @jsw29 OK, 2nd and last stupid question,  so what is the probability of a non-zero?

Comment: "non-zero probability" means any probability greater than zero, so it may happen. It may be very unlikely. Like you winning the jackpot in the lottery every week for the next year. It's not impossible. It is very, very, very unlikely. The probability is a tiny bit more than zero. That's non-zero probability.

Comment: I think that in everyday speech non-zero chance really just means: there is some chance that.

Comment: I agree that "non-zero" does not, in itself, imply "very close to zero".  It MAY be very close to zero (e.g. one in a billion), but it may be reasonably possible (e.g. 25% or so).

Answer (score -1):

Literally, a non-zero chance means that something may happen. It is actually used in different ways, and you need to distinguish from context. And sometimes it's not entirely clear In your examples:

**There is a non-zero chance that the feedback may matter.**

**There is a non-zero chance that they will pay attention to some of the responses.**

The tone how it is said will likely tell you whether it is more sarcastically (yes, it's possible, but in my experience it's not going to happen) or just slightly hopeful (I don't think it will happen, but it might; let's hope for the best).

**There is a non-zero chance that he is the villain we are looking for.**

Unlike your examples, we don't expect someone to be a villain. We expect feedback to matter, or someone paying attention to responses. So here it is the other way round: We are saying that there is a reasonably good chance that he is indeed the villain.