# Why do some people say “negative growth” instead of using a single word indicating a decrease?

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions, phrase-origin, oxymoron

I am not a native English speaker, nor am I an economist.

I have heard the term "negative growth" used in the context of Gross National Product (GNP), and it seems that it is also used in other fields.

This term has always amused me as it sounds like an oxymoron, and I would like to understand why and how that term became popular.

Comment: A rate of growth, or a rate of change, can be positive or negative.

Comment: [Here's an entertaining rant on the subject](https://www.dailymaverick.co.za/article/2020-05-06-mind-your-language-negative-growth-is-a-nonsensical-term-that-needs-to-be-locked-down/) - it does seem to show a desire to abstract language from reality. Possibly it's less damaging to their career for a politician to say "negative growth" than "recession".

Comment: *Positive/negative growth* is a term of art in economics. That means it doesn't apply to all situations or interpretations.

Comment: @Robusto  Would "negative growth" mean the same as "no growth"? Perhaps that's the reason why the expression's grown in popularity? It fools listeners and voters into thinking that the economy is merely stagnant when in fact it is losing money.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm not an economist, but I've seen "zero growth" as well as "no growth" and "flat" describe a growth rate of zero. Negative means less than zero.

Comment: It might have to do with "growth" being a defined term in the field of economics, whereas "shrinkage" is more informal.

Answer (score 4):

The two answers that have been posted so far both seem to regard those who use this phrase as engaged in some kind of rhetorical manipulation of their audiences, of trying to present something bad as if it were not quite so bad.

There is, however, a perfectly rational, not at all manipulative, motivation behind the terms such as *negative growth*. The everyday terms *growth* and *shrinkage* are not etymologically related, which may leave the wrong impression that they are **qualitatively** different. Growth and shrinkage are, however, two parts of the **same** scale; the difference between them is purely **quantitative**. The term *negative growth* brings that out: it makes it clear that the measurements along the dimension of growth (and not some other dimension) have produced a negative number. That, in turn, promotes overall clarity in thinking about such matters (for example it makes it obvious that negative growth at one time can be offset by positive growth at another time).

For the same reasons one may choose to speak of, say, negative gain, rather than loss, and negative acceleration, rather than slowing down. Surely, nobody can accuse those who use the term *negative acceleration*, in the context of mechanics, of trying to manipulate their audiences for some nefarious purpose.

Incidentally, the same question that the OP is asking about *negative growth* could be asked, and the same answer given, about *zero growth*.

Comment: Related: [How infrequent is “a non-zero chance”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470486).

Comment: Yes, it’s a single scale. We also use a single column to express positive and negative change. This is the case in science, technology, engineering, and mathematics, not just economics. Whether growth, positive or negative, is good depends on what’s being measured. A positive growth rate in Covid-19 cases is not good, whereas a negative rate (a decline) in hospitalizations is good.

Comment: This answer was partially a response to the original version of David's answer, which summarily dismissed this way of speaking as 'verbal diarrhoea' and 'undergraduate nonsense'. What is now posted as his answer is a completely new, far more balanced, answer, and it in many, but not all, respects agrees with this one.

Comment: Good answer. Also, using another word such as "reduction" requires more qualifier, like "reduction in GDP", otherwise, if it's just in the context of growth, "reduction" can mean "the growth is less compared to last year". So since we still need more words, "negative growth" is fine here. (this argument may not be applicable to "shrinkage")

Answer (score -1):

The word 'shrink' means to get smaller, but it also carries the connotation of lessening, in a pejorative manner.

For example, the phrase 'shrinking violet,' which means a very shy young woman and carries a negative connotation. If someone 'shrinks from their responsibility,' it means they are lazy or lack courage. In general usage, the word 'shrink' carries a negative connotation.

So, in this case, in saying 'negative growth,' which is a technical term in economics, there is less implicit judgement. It's merely part of something that changes - growth, which fluctuates between positive and negative.

Therefore, 'negative growth' sounds more clinical and has less emotional impact on the listener, and ironically, less negative connotation.

Answer (score -3):

**Interpretation of the question**

The question is asks why unnamed individuals use the term “negative growth” to describe a change in Gross Domestic Product, rather than a simpler term such as “reduction” or “decrease”. It also suggests this is an oxymoron. Although the latter point can be answered by objective analysis, the former would seem to lie in the realms of individual and crowd psychology rather than linguistic evolution.

I therefore address my (revised) answer to a modified question that I feel is within the remit of this site.

> Are there any circumstances in which the expression “negative growth”
> cannot be replaced by a simpler term such as “reduction” or
> “decrease”?

**Revised Answer**

In English there are a many pairs of words indicating opposite quantitative changes: On the one hand, for example, increase/augmentation/growth, on the other decrease/decline/reduction/diminution/shrinkage/fall. The simplest and clearest form of (especially verbal) communication would seem to be to use the appropriate word for the direction of change rather than negating a term implying the opposite.

A problem arises in technical work where one is dealing with tabular or graphical data. If one chooses as dependent variable a term that indicates a quantitative trend in a particular direction, such as *growth* in GDP, then numerical values for a counter-trend will be negative. *Can this be avoided, and, if not, do tabulated negative values need to be expressed as such in a textual or verbal commentary?*

Sometimes this can be *avoided by choosing a neutral term*, rather than one indicating a positive or negative trend. For example “*Change* in GDP” is perfectly acceptable for the axis of a graph (and can be abbreviated as ΔGDP if short of space in a table). The change may be positive or negative, but can be expressed in writing as such, or for verbal communication as an increase or decrease.

Sometimes the choice of positive or negative trend is *dictated by language*. The opposite of acceleration is deceleration, the opposite of inflation is deflation, but there is no neutral word “celeration” or “flation” that can be used in table or graph. One chooses the term expressing the direction of the expected change and can use the opposite term in a commentary.

In the current example one suspects that “growth” rather than “change” is chosen for *psychological or political reasons*, as wars and pestilence are hardly unprecedented. Regardless, if clarity of communication is key, I can see no justification for writing or saying a “negative growth in GDP” rather than a “fall or decline in GDP”

**Reasons**

I will repeat my assertion that use of this kind of expression — oxymoron or not — is **bad** for clarity of communication. I think it has a number of causes. Information about technical subjects is often difficult to express in short, clear sentences, and this can lead to a habit of unnecessary complexity. Sometimes professions like to give themselves a mystique by using terminology that is incomprehensible to the layman. And new recruits, especially, copy this either mindlessly or deliberately to show they belong to the tribe.

I therefore have no regrets in pointing out the nakedness of the Emperor, even though his empire is likely to strike back with downvotes.

Comment: The expression ["negative growth"](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Foreign_Economic_Trends_and_Their_Implic/hJA4AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22negative+growth%22&pg=RA20-PA8&printsec=frontcover) has been around at least since the 1960s, it wasn't so absurd then, was it?  *"The negative growth rate in 1970 for several important crops retarded the overall gains for crop production to a low 2.3 percent.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA — “It wasn’t absurd then, was it?” I actually learned to write direct English from my D. Phil. supervisor in the late 60s. I think he would have regarded it as inflated at least. He was very restrained in expressing himself and left others to pass more extreme judgments. Fowler defends “prior to” over “before” but presents no argument. Should we pay deference because of his or the expression’s age? And what an example! I think it makes my case. Retarded indeed!

Comment: Not my DV but calling the expression verbal diarrhoea is significantly inflated. It depends on the situation and who uses it.